# Am I nothing more than my Dasein?

Tags: death, heidegger, self

I believe Dasein is the Being of a human life, and that Dasein essentially has [Being-in-the-world](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger/#BeiWor).

I think I've finally got a handle on how to compare philosophy "East" and "West" and just need to know whether Dasein, which is nothing when it is complete, and we die, is all there is to "me".

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're relating Dasein to ideas from 'Eastern' philosophy. This is fine, but frankly I cannot do it. The many and various meanings awarded to 'Dasein' make it a minefield of misunderstandings.

It seems relevant that when late in life Heidegger read Dr. Suzuki on Zen he commented 'This is what I have been trying to say in all my writing'. In this case there will be a definite connection between Dasein and the Brahman of non-dualism and the 'Buddha-nature' of the Buddhists and so forth. But with no clear definition the word 'Dasein' may just confuse the issues.

If we define Dasein in a certain way then it would be all there is to you, in a way. It might be better to say that by reduction Dasein is all there is, leaving 'you' as a fiction. I'm not sure why you say it is 'nothing when complete' since what is non-contingent cannot be nothing, but it could certainly be a conceptual void. This would be for the same reason as Kant's thing-in-itself' is such a void, that it has no distinguishing attributes or qualities (or, if you like, it has them all).

How far to take this connection between Dasein and the Perennial view of the non-contingent I wouldn't like to say. I'm not sure it's helpful to approach 'Eastern' philosophy from the direction of Heidegger and suspect it would create a muddle. Coming back to him later, armed with an acquaintance with the non-dual literature,    seems a better idea.

Comment: are you trying to convey the idea that any unrepeatable thing [one] is everything [one]?

Comment: @another_name - I'm not sure what you mean here. I don't use the word 'unrepeatable'.

Comment: ok, sorry peter

Answer (score 0):

As that SEP link you gave points out, being-in-the-world is not something that dasein 'has'; being in the world is the essential (in the philosophical sense) and intractable aspect of dasein. To copy over their citation from "Being in Time":

> Being-in is not a ‘property’ which Dasein sometimes has and sometimes
>   does not have, and without which it could be just as well as it could
>   be with it. It is not the case that man ‘is’ and then has, by way of
>   an extra, a relationship-of-Being towards the ‘world’—a world with
>   which he provides himself occasionally. Dasein is never ‘proximally’
>   an entity which is, so to speak, free from Being-in, but which
>   sometimes has the inclination to take up a ‘relationship’ towards the
>   world. Taking up relationships towards the world is possible only
>   because Dasein, as Being-in-the-world, is as it is. This state of
>   Being does not arise just because some entity is present-at-hand
>   outside of Dasein and meets up with it. Such an entity can ‘meet up
>   with’ Dasein only in so far as it can, of its own accord, show itself
>   within a world.

With that in mind, 'me' and 'my' are particular relationships to the world, and thus are aspects of dasein. But 'me' and 'my' are contingent phenomena — some things are 'me' and 'mine', other things are not 'me' and not 'mine' — and thus they cannot be identical to dasein, which is non-contingent. Talking about '*my* dasein' reverses the relationship in a problematic way, like talking about a feather's goose, or a hoof's horse. It gives the property primacy over the entity.

Dasein is all there is to 'me', sure, because 'me' does not exist outside of dasein. But 'me' is not all there is to dasein. When we die, 'me' ends, but I don't know if that says anything about dasein.

Comment: i did say "essentially" has, so i'm not sure what your point is? and you don't show that Dasein is all there is to me

Comment: Part of philosophy is expressing points clearly. Your statement expressly contradicts what Heidegger said. If you'd meant it to be in agreement you should have worded it differently; if you'd meant it to be a critique, you should have expounded on it. We cannot read your mind, we can only read your words, so it is up to you to make your words clear. And yes, I answered your question in the last two paragraphs. Dasein and 'me' are not identical. I suggest you reread my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are both a human biological individual, a human person, a citizen of some country,  and a Dasein.

These 4 entities count as one, but there is a conceptual distinction between them.

As a human biological individual, you have a " nature", an "essence", you are an instantiation of some universal type or a member of a species.

As a Dasein, you have no " essence": you can't say that you have to be such and such, you simply have to be, period; your " essence" lies in your existence; you " have to be", you are " thrown in the world".

As Dasein, you are unique : many other human beings can be a human being like you; but only you can be yourself. " Dasein has in each case mine-ness".

"Human being" is what you are; " Dasein" is who you are.

Reference : Heidegger, Being and Time, §9.

Answer (score 0):

What is Dasein ?

1 It is existence

2 It is in each case mine

This is a preliminary definition of Dasein but Heiddegger then defines Dasein as Being in the world . Now can we be something more than Dasein ? We can be something more than Dasein when we view Dasein as something that has an essence . To treat Dasein as something that has an essence is to place Dasein on a par with objects . So we can be something more than Dasein when we mistake what we are .

Answer (score 0):

If Dasein means existence it can mean me; but not mine.

This link considered as of the East, denies all the body related things except 'me': https://meditativemind.org/nirvana-shatakam-complete-lyrics-meaning-chidananda-roopah-shivoham-shivoham/

Actually the world is in me, not 'I am in the world'.  But when I/we consider my/our body as me I/we feel it as utter foolishness. And this felling is rational.

> Am I nothing more than my Dasein?

Truth is changeless.  So, Dasein, when it means existence, becomes a synonym of Truth...I mean, without being a thing that our mind can apprehend/imagine. That is, we would be compelled to enhance its definition by giving more attributives. Then the triviality of the term 'nothing more than' conveys would also disappear.